# load angular2 module into another app

Tags: angular, module, components, angular2-routing, bootstrapping

I have a big angular2 app and I want to split it into several autonomous apps, so that every app can be bootstrapped alone. So far so good.

I want, however, a "main app" which contains a navbar and that can display components from the "children apps".

I tried to import in my main app a module from a child app and I managed successfully to display a component. Problems begin to occour when the imported module has its own dependancies (like third-party node modules) or services.

How can I achieve these goals:

- have several apps which can be bootstrapped alone
- have a main app that can display components from others app, **with a single bootstrap**.

A good solution would be to trasform an app into a library and then install it as a npm package. Is it possible? I mean automatically..

Thank you.